# Why is null * 0 = null in sql when it is not in math or other languages

Tags: sql, math, null

Why is '`null * 0 = null`'?

There can not be any other result, why is `null*0` not evaluated to `0`?
Is it possible that this has to do with some higher level math which i am unfamiliar with, or would it may be have some implications for the dbms?

Comment: Just about any operation with `NULL` results in `NULL`, except for `is null` and `is not null`.  (Note:  `NULL` boolean values are treated as "false".)  That is the way that SQL is defined.  I don't think "higher level math" has anything to do with it.

Comment: It's my assumption that it is easier and safer to assume that at the end of an operation that involves `NULL` that it would result in `NULL` rather than treating the `NULL` as a value of some sort.

Comment: Amply discussed at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null_(SQL) (null propagation, 3-valued logic, joining on nulls etc etc)

Comment: NB, the description of the tag [null](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/null) at StackOverflow is "Null means *nothing* or *unknown*, depending on context."

Comment: @GordonLinoff I don't think NULL boolean values are treated as false are they? I thought they are treated as `Not true` which might be inferred to be false, but is actually unknown, therefore not false or true. I confess, I haven't actually checked the standard, but certainly [MySQL](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/95d093/2), and [Postgresql](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/e6ee7/1) do not treat a null boolean value as false.

Comment: NULL is treated as unknown in boolean logic, its neither false nor true.

Comment: @GarethD . . . You are correct.  I was using "false" as a shorthand for saying the comparison would fail.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`NULL` in SQL represents "unknown". When a math operation is performed with an unknown, you could not possibly get anything known, even when you multiply it by zero. Similar situation happens in math: although multiplying any number by zero yields zero, [multiplying an infinity by zero doesn't](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/28940).

Answer (score 7):

It's a sane design choice to maintain `NULL`ness through all manners of operation. Making an exception for multiplication by 0 would raise inconsistencies, e.g.

```
0  * NULL; # 0
1  * NULL; # NULL
.5 * NULL; # HALFNULL? ;-)
```

Comment: NULL or YES = YES; it is guarsnteed to be yes, 0*NULL can also be guaranteed to be 0, but its not in SQL.

Comment: Allowing `NULL` to assume a `false` value in boolean context may be semantically inconsistent, if you will, but it *is* in keeping with most programming languages. Choose your double standard ;-)

Comment: Oh, what i meant was that in SQL null or yes results in yes.

Answer (score 3):

It's simply part of the ANSI standard. Some cases can be overriden on some systems (for example, comparing nulls on MS SQL).

All in all, it's about avoiding undefined behaviour. What *should* `null * 0` give? What type is the `null`? There's just too many things that can kill predictability. In programming, `null` is mostly handled as a special value, and for good reasons - `I don't know` is something else than `No`, after all :) Of course, Objective-C designers wouldn't agree with me... :D

As for what this has to do with math, well, `null` isn't a real number, obviously, so `null * 0` would be undefined for real numbers. You'd have to have a "bigger" number category that would contain your `null`, and it would have to have the `*` operation redefined (or not). When you're dealing with math, don't forget the constraints - rules like `A * 0 = 0` *only* apply inside their number categories. `Infinity * 0` is *not* `0` - it's undefined.

Comment: In Objective-C, nil and Nil are very different from NULL.